# Add total discount coupons amount in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, discount

I am trying to add up all of my added coupons to get a discount total in the checkout. I tried adding a variable at the top of the checkout template file and doing ++ for each entry but I throws errors.

Any ideas how to add the values to a variable to get a total?

The checkout totals regenerate if you alter a value so I found my answer being outputted each time the loop runs.

My code:

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
        <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
            <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
            <td><?php $helloworld = wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon )++; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily using some existing WC_Cart methods.

So in the template `checkout/oreder-review.php`, just after this:

```
        <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You will insert the following code *(after line 69)*:

```
        <?php
            $discount_excl_tax_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_discount_total();
            $discount_tax_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_discount_tax_total();
            $discount_total = $discount_excl_tax_total + $discount_tax_total;
        if( ! empty($discount_total) ): ?>
            <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
                <th><?php _e('Discount total','woocommerce'); ?></th>
                <td><?php echo wc_price(-$discount_total) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Tested and works.

[image]